# ESRI Shape to GML in os Vector Map Local format converter

Tags: gis, shapefile, esri, gml

I'm looking for some kind of converter. I need to convert `ESRI Shape files (*.shp)` to `GML` (but it's to be in os `Vector Map Local` format - `VML`). Does anyone know any?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL can do it, using ogr2ogr:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

See [the comments on this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29169/quantim-gis-python-script-to-convert-shapefile-to-gml) for syntax.